# Adding function/stored procedure names in SQL table and calling them in c# project

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a project where I have a table of randomly generated 4 character codes i.e ABCD.

The project is about restricting some of the randomly generated codes if they meet certain restrictions i.e containing certain words (curse words or reserved words). The user should be able to enter as many restricted words as they want, and the app loops through all the codes in my codes table and if they match any of the restriction this is to be flagged with restriction id.

Now so far I have 3 restriction  (could be more than these 3 and more custom logic needed)

1. StartsWith
2. EndsWith
3. Contains

My restriction table looks like

```
Restriction ID | Restriction Type | Description 
1              | 1                | HQ
2              | 3                | BAD


Code Table looks like
ID             | Postcode         | Restriction ID
1              | ABCD             | NULL
2              | ABHQ             | 1
```

My question is about how to be smart around restriction types and how to implement their logic, I.e. each restriction type will need a different method with different logic for checking if that new type should restrict postcodes.

So in my code..

```
//Loop through each code
For each code

     //Loop through each restriction 
     For each restriction
     ?? How to implement custom logic for each different restriction type i.e contains / startswith / endwith.
```

I guess I could do a switch statement and hardcode the method to call by type ID or I was thinking maybe in the restriction type table adding a column for Method which could could have the .net method to call for that type or maybe stored procedure ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to think about other possible restriction types that could be needed in the future. If those 3 are enough, then you may be over complicating things just to accommodate for flexibility that will never be used.

For example, if you stick to those 3 restriction types, then a simple solution, without even using stored procedure, could be:

```
-- Select all restricted codes and their restriction type.
SELECT c.ID, c.Postcode, t.RestrictionId
FROM CodeTable c
    INNER JOIN RestrictionTable t 
    ON c.Postcode LIKE 
              CASE t.RestrictionType 
                 WHEN 1 THEN t.Description + '%'
                 WHEN 2 THEN '%' + t.Description
                 WHEN 3 THEN '%' + t.Description + '%'
                 ELSE t.Description 
              END
```

Comment: Yeah I need to check if any other restriction types can apply, I can't think of anymore. One more question I was going to ask, how would I handle the following where certain letters/number look alike i.e SAD,5AD. Is there anything out there to generate all the combinations of certain words which contain letters/numbers which looks alike ?

Comment: You can probably use regular expressions for that. Be aware that building a profanity filter is a much harder problem that it seems. See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html    and also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem